# Wordpress how to get the post thumbnail inside a figure tag

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, thumbnails, custom-wordpress-pages

I am running a query loop and want that '*if*' the post has a featured image, it needs to be inside a `<figure>` tag. But the featured image's `<img>` tag is appearing before the `<figure>` tag. What could be the reason?

```
        foreach($posts as $post){
            setup_postdata($post);
            

            echo '<article class="pet_post">';
                if(has_post_thumbnail()) { echo '<figure class="post_thumbnail">'. the_post_thumbnail('full') . '</figure>'; };
                echo '<h1 class="post_title">'. get_the_title() . '</h1>';
                echo '<p class="pet_seller">'. get_the_content() . '</p>';
                echo '<form method="POST">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="post-id" value="'. get_the_ID() . '">';
                    echo '<button type="submit" name="delete-post">Delete this post</button>';
                echo '</form>';   
            echo '</article>';
        };
```

The problem can be better understood with this image:
[image]

Comment: Well no, coz the img tag is inserted by Wordpress as the result of using the_post_thumbnail('full'). img tags do not take a closing slash like <img/> anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `the_post_thumbnail` function which echo the image by default which happens sooner than echoing out the `figure` tag.

Replace

```php
echo '<figure class="post_thumbnail">'. the_post_thumbnail('full') . '</figure>';
```

with

```php
echo '<figure class="post_thumbnail"><img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), "full") . '"></figure>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Clever solution. :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe this approach is also acceptable.

```
<figure class="post_thumbnail">
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { echo the_post_thumbnail('full'); }; ?>
</figure>
```